# Display all from queryset rather than only one element

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am trying to display all item from my queryset at the moment it is only displaying one

Below is my code that is returning only the first element from my queryset special_list:

views.py

```
try:
    try:
        specail_list = Special.objects.get(promotion=True, sp_code=promocode, start__lte=date_instance, minimum_stay__lte=nights, object_id=room_filter.id, end__gte=date_instance, is_active=True, member_deal=False)
        is_promo=True
    except:
        specail_list = Special.objects.filter(promotion=False, start__lte=date_instance, minimum_stay__lte=nights, object_id=room_filter.id, end__gte=date_instance, is_active=True, member_deal=False)
        is_promo = False

    min_stay_check_end = chek_in + datetime.timedelta(days=specail_list.minimum_stay - 1)
    min_stay_check_start = check_out - datetime.timedelta(days=specail_list.minimum_stay)

    if min_stay_check_end > (specail_list.end.date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) and (check_out + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) > specail_list.end.date():
        specail_list = None

    if min_stay_check_start < (specail_list.start.date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) and (chek_in < specail_list.start.date()  + datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
        specail_list = None

except:
    specail_list = None

try:
    for element in specail_list:
        if element.discount_type =="NIGHTS":
            if specials_nights < (element.minimum_stay * int(nights/element.minimum_stay)): 
                discount = element.nights_off_discount(Decimal(cost_of_rooms))
                print(discount)
                specials_nights += 1
             else:
                 discount = 0
         elif element.discount_type =="FLAT":
                 discount = Decimal(element.pay_days)
         else:
             discount = element.discount(1,Decimal(cost_of_rooms),adults,children,no_of_rooms)

             cost_of_rooms = Decimal(cost_of_rooms)-Decimal(discount)

             price_instance= math.ceil((Decimal(price_instance) * Decimal(ex.rate))*100)/100
                                cost_of_rooms = math.ceil((Decimal(cost_of_rooms) * Decimal(ex.rate))*100)/100

             discount_recived =Decimal(price_instance)-Decimal(cost_of_rooms)
             newli.append({'room': room_instance, 'display_order':room_filter.display_order, 'rm': room_filter, 'date': date_instance, 'quantity':av['quantity'], 'price':int(price_instance),'error':True,'discount':discount_recived,'sp_name':element.name,'sp_description':element.description,'sp_start':element.start,'sp_end':element.end,'count_sp':specail_list})









   discount_count.append({'room':room_instance,'normal_rate':price_instance,'discount':discount_recived})
   except Exception:                               
                            try:
                                price_instance = math.ceil((Decimal(price_instance) * Decimal(ex.rate))*100)/100
                                cost_of_rooms = math.ceil((Decimal(cost_of_rooms) * Decimal(ex.rate))*100)/100
                            except:
                               pass
                            discount_recived =Decimal(price_instance)-Decimal(cost_of_rooms)
                            newli.append({'room': room_instance, 'display_order':room_filter.display_order, 'rm': room_filter, 'date': date_instance, 'quantity':av['quantity'], 'price': int(price_instance),'error':True})
                            discount_count.append({'room':room_instance,'normal_rate':price_instance,'discount':discount_recived})


   newlist = sorted(newli, key=itemgetter('quantity'))
```

template

```
{% if rooms.discount_percent > 0 or rooms.sp_name %}
{% for i in rooms.sp_name|slice:"2" %}  
    <div class="room-plan row ">

        <input id="roomid_{{rooms.rm.id}}" type="checkbox" class="room_id" name ="select_room" value="{{rooms.rm.id}}" >
        <span class="plan-title" id="sp_{{rooms.rm.id}}">{% if rooms.sp_name %}{{rooms.sp_name}}{% else %}{{rooms.discount_percent}}% Discount{% endif %}</span>
        <a class="link"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#discount_{{rooms.rm.id}}"> Rate Details</a>

        <span class="cost" id="{{rooms.rm.id}}">
            {{current_symbol}}{{rooms.discountprice}}
        </span>
        <span class="per">per {{rooms.rm.rate_based_on}}</span>

    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

On My template is returning two items  but both of them is displaying the first element form my queryset :

```
specail_list = Special.objects.filter(promotion=False, start__lte=date_instance, minimum_stay__lte=nights, object_id=room_filter.id, end__gte=date_instance, is_active=True, member_deal=False)
```

Note : I have updated my code but still not working it is not diplaying any items from specail_list on my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written to only return 1 element. If you want to get all results your second query with [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) ist correct (well....without that `[0]`)

The moment you receive multiple items in return, you have to change your code. You're no longer dealing with one element but a managed list. Each of these items has `.minimum_stay` and they could all be different to each other. So you'll need to loop over your queryset to do whatever you want to do.

```
for element in special_list:
    # do whatever you need to do/compare with that element
```

Comment: thanks @Bloodmallet for this great idea i have managed to crack it